# Python variable equal to class method? Syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

so I'm starting to learn python and I need to write a script that edits a CSV file. I found this online and had a few questions about what it's exactly doing since the original programmer didn't explain. My question right now though is about syntax. I'm a little confused about some of these lines:

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = 
     "Select a file", filetypes = (("csv files", "*.csv"),))
```

So my first question is what root equals. I understand I imported two modules called Tkinter and tkFileDialog(Correct me if I'm wrong) into my file. I then created a variable called root and set it equal to a method call?

```
root = Tkinter.tk()
```

Next, what does this line do? Is filename a method in one of those modules? I read something about widgets...are widgets methods? As in the word is used interchangeably?

```
root.filename
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I then created a variable called root and set it equal to a method call?"

Actually, what you did is saved the _result_ of the method call to the variable root

Comment: To see what `root.filename` is and what effects assigning to it has, you should check the documentation for the `Tkinter.Tk()` method to see what it is that it returned

Comment: when you don't know what kind of object you have, you can always do `print root` or `help(root)`

Comment: You should seriously consider learning Python 3, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, people suggested that as well, but said I should start with python 2

Comment: Learning Python 2 now as a precursor to learning Python 3 makes about as much sense as learning Shakespearean English as a precursor to learning modern English.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask such fundamental questions, when this can all be answered by working through a basic python tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You may benefit more form some youtube tutorials on python methods/functions and classes but I can answer your questions in general terms.

> So my first question is what root equals.

`root` is the variable name assigned to the instance that is being created with `tkinter.Tk()`

This allows you to interact with that instance of tkinter and you can use `root` to place widgets on the main window of the GUI.

> Next, what does this line do? root.filename

`root.filename` is only a variable name. `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` is the class method being used to get the file and assign the file information to the variable name `root.filename`

So what you are doing here is importing the library `tkinter` that contains many class methods that can be used to build and manipulate a GUI interface.

note that for an instance of tkinter you will need a `mainloop()` at the end of your code to make it work. So at the end of your code you will need to have something like `root.mainloop()` to make sure the program will work as long as everything else is done correctly.

Comment: Is it bad notation for the way that variable was named though? As in, dots are usually used to call methods, so when they wrote that line: ' root.filename ' it makes it look like theirs a method called filename. Also, I ran the script and filemanager popped up that allowed me to select a file. I thought you said it wouldn't work if I didn't call ' mainloop() '

Comment: I know when I first started learning python I would use something like `root.text = Text(root)` to create a text box in tkinter. It doesn't hurt the program any but there is a PEP8 naming convention I follow now for naming of variables/attributes, function/methods and classes.

Comment: It probably would have been better to name it something like rootFilename or something. Awesome, thanks! I'll go look for some tutorials.

Comment: @MichaelBenton: yes that would have been one format some people use. I would have done something like root_filename or just filename.